# Secure Login From Script or Database?

Tags: php, authentication

I have a noob question.

Suppose I want to develop an Admin Panel and it has only one Admin.

So instead of authenticating the admin from database information I want to do it from the script. I mean I will assign admin username and password to variables and match these with given username and password.

So the question is which one is secure more and why? 
1. Matching the username and password from the database?
or
2. Matching the username and password from predefined variables in the script?

Comment: database is more secure, because if you store password in a script user can easily hack your password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nether is more secure than the other. It all depends how it's stored.

Normally I already have a database connection set up so using that has little over head.

If you have your credentials in a file in document root. Then someone who knows the file name can just go to the file directly. If you put the credentials in a .php file it could still be compromised if at some time the webserver config get messed to where the php parser is not being called and the file is sent raw. So to secure against that I put that information outside the document root. Much like you should be putting your database credentials out side the document root.

Another option would be to protect your application through the .htaccess .

Answer (score 0):

It's good from database so you can update the password everytime you need from admin, but you should using PDO not using manual mysql_query, because PDO is secure from sql injection :)

Comment: PDO isn't secure from SQL injection. Prepared statements are secured against SQL injection.

Comment: yes as you know PDO is having prepared statement where it's safe from sql injection and another way you can combine with strip_tags